# How to replace digits except one character in sed?

Tags: sed, replace, digits

I tried many ways to replace digits into `@XXXX` but I always get `@1212` or just `XXXX` instead. I know I tried using this code:

```
sed -E 's/1212/XXXX/' file
```

but the only thing I want is to match digits `[0-9]{4}` except one character @.

file:

```
line @1212
```

and here the codes I've been using it but didn't work.

```
sed -E 's/[^@][0-9]{4}/XXXX/' file


sed -E 's/[@][0-9]{4}$/XXXX/' file
```

Comment: We may have a language barrier, but what are you trying to do? Change `line @1212` into `line @xxxx`? How about `sed 's/@[0-9]{4}/@xxxx/'`?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Beta Yes, I'm sorry I didn't put my desired output, thanks to Cyrus for letting me know. The code you show me, it works. Thank you.